# Simple: NSArray object to Double?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, casting

I have a NSArray with numbers and I want to get the value of an item of the array and assign it to a double. In my attempt of simple casting:

```
lat = (double)[storesList.latitudes objectAtIndex:i];
```

I get the error: "Pointer value used where a floating point value was expected".

Please help!

Thank you,

F.

Comment: What type of objects are actually stored in the array? :)

Comment: Be sure to check the gray checkmark next to one of the answers.

Comment: I'm sure he knows, but good reminder.

Comment: ( @BoltClock He'd commented on two answers but hadn't accepted one, so I figured it was worth a reminder.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you say that your array is consisting of number (NSNumber class), that you may should get the value next way:

```
double lat = [[storeList.latitudes objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
```

Comment: Obj C FTW, wasted an hour on that. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You cannot cast an `NSNumber` object to a primitive `double` type value. Use the `doubleValue` method of `NSNumber` instead, like this:

```
lat = [[storesList.latitudes objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code

```
double lat = [[storeList.latitudes objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
```

Thank you